# Algorithm for finding least $b$ such that $2^b \equiv 2^a \pmod{m}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Let $n > 1$ be a positive integer. Are there any known algorithms for finding the smallest positive integer $b > 0$ such that

$$
2^b \equiv 2^a \pmod{n}
$$

for some integer $0 \le a < b$? How would one find such a $b$?

Comment: Doesn't this immediately reduce to finding minimal $c:=b-a$ such that $2^c \equiv 1$?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Well it does at least if $m$ is odd...

Comment: Thanks, I think that solves it. If $n$ is even write $n = 2^w n'$ for some positive integer $w$, then find $c'$ such that $2^{c'} \equiv 1 \pmod{n'}$.

Comment: $c$ is multiplicative order two by modulo $n$: $c=ord_2(n)$. If $a$ is given, then $b>a$ can be non exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to extend my comment, with Henning Makholm's Caveat, to a reduction:

We have
$$(*) \qquad\qquad2^a \equiv 2^b \text{ mod } n \Leftrightarrow 2^a(2^{b-a}-1) \equiv 0\text{ mod }n. $$

Write $n =2^k \cdot n'$ with $n'$ odd.

If $a \le k-1$, then $(*)$ has no solution with $b > a$.

If, on the other hand, $a\ge k$, then $(*)$ is equivalent to $2^{b-a} \equiv 1$ mod $n'$, i.e. we have to find the order of $2\in (\mathbb Z/n')^\times$.

Secondly, after this reduction, I am pretty sure there is no good algorithm for computing such an order in general. Namely, this is essentially the [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm#Modular_arithmetic). Compare e.g. [Easy way to find the order of elements in a finite field](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1700534/96384) and [Finding the order of elements of a quotient ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1945007/96384). Of course one should first factor $n'$ into prime powers $n'= \prod_{p \vert n} p^{k_p}$, and in the case $n' = p^k$ one can use Fermat's little theorem to see the order should be a divisor of $p^{k-1}(p-1)$, etc. For small $n'$, then a smart-brute-force calculation will quickly give results.

But if $n'$ is, say, $2^{73567542844189849778256010093567127647}-1$, I think some people would give you real money if you have a good algorithm for that.